# Why aren't div backgrounds updated in a loop after the first one?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

I am calling a function to set the backgrounds of several container divs to previously uploaded images. I use Ajax to get back a list (data) of image names and on success, I try to set the background of each div to the correct image. The data received is correct and the alert pops up 12 times with the correct values each time - however, only the first div background is actually set.

```
success: function(data) {
        var images = data.split(',');
        var i = 0;
        for(i = 0; i < 12; i++){
            $("#mm"+(i+1).toString()).css('background-image', 'url(uploads/'+images[i]+')');
            $("#mm"+(i+1).toString()).css('background-size', '100%');
            alert("set #mm"+(i+1).toString()+" "+images[i]);
        }
    }
```

Is this something to do with Ajax or am I missing something very simple? It seems to me the code above should work...I have checked developer tools and there are no errors, I have checked the file are all in the correct place and accessible, and I have checked the tomcat logs and all seems fine..

I have also tried unrolling the loop but the result is the same - only the first image is loaded:

```
$("#mm1").css('background-image', 'url(uploads/'+images[0]+')');
                             $("#mm1").css('background-size', '100%');
                             $("#mm2").css('background-image', 'url(uploads/'+images[1]+')');
                             $("#mm2").css('background-size', '100%');
                             $("#mm3").css('background-image', 'url(uploads/'+images[2]+')');
                             $("#mm3").css('background-size', '100%');
                             $("#mm4").css('background-image', 'url(uploads/'+images[3]+')');
                             $("#mm4").css('background-size', '100%');
                             $("#mm5").css('background-image', 'url(uploads/'+images[4]+')');
                             $("#mm5").css('background-size', '100%');
                             $("#mm6").css('background-image', 'url(uploads/'+images[5]+')');
                             $("#mm6").css('background-size', '100%');
                             $("#mm7").css('background-image', 'url(uploads/'+images[6]+')');
                             $("#mm7").css('background-size', '100%');
```

The HTML code is as follows (there are 12 in total):

```
                        <div id="uploadsContainer" class="mm1Container">
                            <div id="mm1" class="mm1 card front face">
                                <form id="mm1Form" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"  action="imageUploadForm.jsp">
                                    <input type="hidden" name="mm" value="mm1" />
                                    <input class="uploads" type="file" name="image" id="image1" value="mm1"/>
                                    <input type="submit" class="btn" value="Upload File"/>
                                </form>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <div id="uploadsContainer" class="mm2Container">
                            <div id="mm2" class="mm2 card front face">
                                <form id="mm2Form" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"  action="imageUploadForm.jsp">
                                    <input type="hidden" name="mm" value="mm2" />
                                    <input class="uploads" type="file" name="image" id="image2" value="mm2"/>
                                    <input type="submit" class="btn" value="Upload File"/>
                                </form>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <div id="uploadsContainer" class="mm3Container">
                            <div id="mm3" class="mm3 card front face">
                                <form id="mm3Form" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"  action="imageUploadForm.jsp">
                                    <input type="hidden" name="mm" value="mm3" />
                                    <input class="uploads" type="file" name="image" id="image3" value="mm3"/>
                                    <input type="submit" class="btn" value="Upload File"/>
                                </form>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </li>
```

The response data from Ajax is html form and is a comma separated list of image names:

```
IMG00808-20120824-1820.jpg, 860296_10151614864350672_1992010847_o.jpg, gentidona.jpg, 4220961.JPG, 4220961.JPG, 4220961.JPG, 40433_422126195671_675790671_5399343_5684255_n.jpg, mum.jpg, IMG_5500.JPG, IMG00817-20120824-1826.jpg, 4220961.JPG, IMG00019-20110219-1844.jpg
```

Comment: Could you also show us the HTML code you have?

Comment: Also ajax response data please?

Comment: I have edited the question above! I have just tested changing mm2 first and that doesn't work so I'm investigating that...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is because you have a space in all image paths but not the first one after you perform the split.

```
data = "IMG00808-20120824-1820.jpg, 860296_10151614864350672_1992010847_o.jpg, gentidona.jpg, 4220961.JPG, 4220961.JPG, 4220961.JPG, 40433_422126195671_675790671_5399343_5684255_n.jpg, mum.jpg, IMG_5500.JPG, IMG00817-20120824-1826.jpg, 4220961.JPG, IMG00019-20110219-1844.jpg";
var images = data.split(',');
// this will result in the following array
images[0] = 'IMG00808-20120824-1820.jpg';
images[1] = ' 860296_10151614864350672_1992010847_o.jpg';
// ... etc
```

You can trim image[x] values before using them to prevent this issue:

```
images[i] = images[i].trim();
```

Comment: aha! you are a genius! let me just try getting rid of that then I'll update you...well spotted, thank you so much, don't think I would ever have got that!

Comment: you're welcome. a second eye always helps with such bugs